# GraphQL Query returns different result depends on argument

Tags: graphql

I would like to know if a query returns different result depends on an argument, let say

```
{
  appDates(opposite:true){
    createdBy
    from
    to
  } 
  appDates(opposite:false){
    date
  } 
}
```

In this case, I can either split the query into 2 different queries/schemas, or reuse the same schema since the SQL structure is similar. Which is a better approach for graphql?